# How to add a freestyle stroke to a specific edge in blender?

Tags: freestyle

I am trying to add a black line (freestyle) to a single edge in blender cycles render. I need help !

Comment: btw, freestyle is not bound to cycles (tags)

Comment: @m.ardito You can use freestyle in cycles

Comment: yes, but binding a strike to an edge has nothing specific for cycles. it works the same for blender internal

Comment: @m.ardito I wanted it for cycles... I'm working on a project

Comment: good, I just pointed out that your main tag "cycles" seems to bind your question to a cycles setup, while this could benefit also who is using blender render. This site is to give answer to you now, and others later....

Comment: @m.ardito oh ok !

Comment: @m.ardito edited my question tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to *Edit mode* and select the edge, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, choose *Mark Freestyle Edge*.
Then go to the *Render Layers* properties tab. Under *Freestyle Line Set*, set up the *Edge Types* as in this screenshot:

[image: Freestyle Edge Types]

[image: Result]
Don't forget to enable *Freestyle* under the *Render* properties tab.